# How does <center> tag still works in HTML5 script when it is being removed?

Tags: html

In HTML5 introduction it is being mentioned that  tag is being removed. In order to test it, I tried the below script:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <center>
    <h1>This is a Heading</h1>
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
  </center>
</body>

</html>
```

How can we test it.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</center>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 1):

The `<center>` tag is deprecated and should be removed going forward. However some browsers have chosen to support it in their current versions most likely to allow older sites to still present correctly.

It being removed means that you shouldn't rely on it always working.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in testing. Try the following code in all browsers.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html> 
    <head> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
    <title>Page Title</title> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
    <center> <h1>This is a Heading</h1> <p>This is a paragraph.</p>     
    </center>        
     </body> 
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without the "center" tag you can use css to align the text. Try following code:

```
!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<meta charset="UTF-8"> 
<title>Page Title</title> 
</head> 
<body > 
<h1 style="text-align: center;">This is a Heading</h1> <p style="text-align: center;">This is a paragraph.</p> 
</body> 
</html>
```